# Can't get the simplest XMLHttpRequest example to work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I'm trying to do the simplest example of an XMLHttpRequest take straight from a tutorial. I have an XML file note.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<note>
    <to>Jimmy</to>
    <from>Paul</from>
    <body>Hello!</body>
</note>
```

and a html with javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>W3Schools Internal Note</h1>
<div>
<b>To:</b> <span id="to"></span><br>
<b>From:</b> <span id="from"></span><br>
<b>Message:</b> <span id="message"></span>
</div>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","note.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("from")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see this is taken straight from W3schools. I try and open the HTML in chrome or IE explorer and I get nothing but...

W3Schools Internal Note

To: 
From: 
Message:

Nothing populated...What simple thing am I missing. Both files are stored in the same local directory.

Thanks

Comment: Did you upload it to a server?

Comment: No just working locally. Opening the .html from a folder on the windows c drive, same folder that the .xml is stored in.

Comment: You should set up a local server.

Comment: Done and working. Thank you